# Set reference to second variable

Tags: c++, reference

I was expecting the value of b to be 100 below, but I get 12. Why is this the case? Clearly my `c = b` line is not assigning c as an alias for b?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 12;
    int& c = a;

    c = 8;

    cout << a << endl;
    c = b;
    c = 100;

    cout << b << endl;


    int bb;
    cin >> bb;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Clearly my `c = b` line is not assigning `c` as an alias for `b`?

Exactly, references cannot be *reseated* in C++.  `c` will always be a reference to `a`.

`c = b` is just a straightforward assignment.

Answer (score 6):

You can't reseat references - your `c = b;` line just assigns to `c` (and thereby also to `a`) the current value of `b`.

When you then assign `100` to `c`, `b` therefore doesn't change, so it still has its original value of `12` when you print it out.

See this FAQ question:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/reseating-refs.html

Answer (score 2):

`c = b` in fact does the following:

1. `c` is a reference to `a`, so whatever operation we request on `c` will actually work on `a`.
2. We're assigning to `c` – that means, by 1., we must in fact assign to `a`.
3. `a` is an lvalue of type `int`, so assigning `b` to it changes the value of `a` to whatever value `b` has at that moment. (For class-type objects, this would call the copy assignment operator.)
4. `b` has the value `12`, so we give this value to `a`.

And that's it. Nothing there changes anything about what `c` refers to: it was `a` previously, and it is `a` afterwards, only `a` now has a different value.

---

Apparently you *want* to reseat `c` so that it then refers to `b`. Well, you can't do that with C++ references, and IMO this is a good thing. But you can do it with pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 12;
    int* c = &a;

    *c = 8;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    c = &b;
    *c = 100;

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

will output what you expected from your program.